# Is it possible to replicate report customization through visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, reporting, dynamic-visualforce

I want to replicate the class style drag and drop report builder (see image) on a visualforce page to upload as a lightning component on the Napili Community.

[image]

Comment: Of course it is. VF is just HTML in the end.....It would be a massive task though. I am sure SF has teams on this. For a single Dev it could be a life's work lol (at least it feel like it to me)

Comment: Check out [Drag-and-Drop with jQuery: Your Essential Guide](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/) and specifically the [last demo](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html).